# Change Python botlle server routes ordering

Tags: python, bottle

I have the follwoing route:

```
@app.route('/<path:path>', method=['POST', 'GET'])
```

How can I access change route ordering to access this route if it placed below

```
@app.route('/helllo/<path:path>', method=['POST', 'GET'])
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to change the route? Or add a second route?

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple `@route` decorators for the same view function, in your case like this:

```py
@app.route('/<path:path>', method=['POST', 'GET'])
@app.route('/helllo/<path:path>', method=['POST', 'GET'])
def your_function(path):
    ...
```

See [documentation](https://www.bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#request-routing)